Si bien-usage with indicative in the present tense and other tenses?
I want to clarify ''si bien''usage and that it is always used in the present indicative to mean altough ,as an alternative to ''aunque''. I mean,it can signify''while'' or ''eventhough ''also.
I see a previous post about its origin
¿Cuál es el origen de la conjunción «si bien»?
In Spanish Homeschool Academy ,it gives the example below which clearly is in the indicative:
Si bien es importante leer mucho, no puedes descuidar la salud de tus ojos.
While it is important to read a lot, you cannot neglect the health of your eyes.
This is the link
https://www.spanish.academy/blog/9-types-of-subordinating-conjunctions-in-spanish-that-will-supercharge-your-fluency/
I also checked Word Reference forum but I found the posts too confusing.
In short,I would like to know if it is always in the present indicative in the present tense.
Also, and I'm sure more confusingly,could someone give me examples of what happens in other tenses with that same conjunction? Future?Preterite?Imperfect?Conditional?
Perhaps,erroneously,I feel it may be easier to use than ''aunque''

"Si bien" is always followed by indicative because it introduces a real situation. When "aunque" introduces a real situation, it is also followed by indicative:

Si bien llueve (it does rain), iremos a ver el eclipse.
Aunque llueve (it does rain), iremos a ver el eclipse.

When "aunque" introduces an uncertain situation, it is followed by subjunctive:

Aunque llueva (it does not rain, but it may), iremos a ver el eclipse.


Very clear explanations. I understand clearly,thank you. I like your eclipse reference also.

Completing the post of @Gustavson, as you said, you can use "si bien" with other tenses. Here you have some examples:
Futuro

Si bien te encontrarás con una señal que indica girar a la izquierda, para llegar a Madrid deberás seguir recto.

Pasado

Si bien estuvo cinco años en Boston, nunca llegó a hablar fluidamente en inglés.

Imperfecto

Si bien salía a correr todos los días, nunca lo hacía sólo, siempre iba con algún amigo.


Great examples and explanation  thanks
